# Putting Excel Tables into a Custom Class

Tags: vba, excel, class

I'm new to using VBA classes, and I think what I want to do -- using them with ListObjects -- is more of an "intermediate" than "beginner" technique.

Let's say I have two tables related to cars.

```
tblCarDesc
ID   MAKE        MODEL      DOORS     ENGINE
1    Chevrolet   Corvette    2         V8
2    Ford        Escort      4         V6
3    Rolls-Royce SilverCloud 4         V8

tblCarProd
ID      COUNTRY  TYPE
1       US       Sport
2       US       Economy
3       UK       Luxury
```

(The same cars are in both tables, and shown by the ID numbers.)

I want to have a class called objCars that includes the fields (columns) from both tables. That way, when referring to Car #3, objCars.Make would be "Rolls-Royce" and objCars.Type would be "Luxury".

1) Is there a way to import both tables into objCars?

Perhaps I would create an array big enough to hold all the columns, then load both tables into it. The tutorial I've been reading says that I would then create a Collection, loop through each row of the array, make a new instance of objCars, and assign objCars.Make, objCars.Model, etc., for each row.  Then each item of the Collection would contain a car. (Or something like that. I don't really know much about Collections either.)  If that's right, is it the best way?

2) How exactly does one refer to a specific car? The examples I've read like to loop through Collections and work on each item therein, but what if I want to extract a particular item? I know the Ford is Car #2; how do I get the objCars.Make and objCars.Model for that particular ID number?

Comment: If your data is so very tabular why not consider a solution along the lines of ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) and their recordsets?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What database technologies are you familiar with please? This is so we can have a common frame of reference.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer that! I'm an intermediate user of Access, but my project is entirely in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

I would have two classes. A class `clsCar` for one car and a class `clsCars` for a collection of cars.

Each of this classes may have setter and getter methods and also may have custom methods if needed. Especially the `clsCars` should have a set of `getBy...`-methods to get a car or a collection of cars from the collection by criterion.

Example:

`clsCar`:

```
Private pID As Long
Private pMAKE As String
Private pMODEL As String
Private pDOORS As Integer
Private pENGINE As String
Private pCOUNTRY As String
Private pTYPE As String

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As Long)
    pID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MAKE() As String
    MAKE = pMAKE
End Property
Public Property Let MAKE(Value As String)
    pMAKE = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MODEL() As String
    MODEL = pMODEL
End Property
Public Property Let MODEL(Value As String)
    pMODEL = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DOORS() As Integer
    DOORS = pDOORS
End Property
Public Property Let DOORS(Value As Integer)
    pDOORS = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ENGINE() As String
    ENGINE = pENGINE
End Property
Public Property Let ENGINE(Value As String)
    pENGINE = Value
End Property

Public Property Get COUNTRY() As String
    COUNTRY = pCOUNTRY
End Property
Public Property Let COUNTRY(Value As String)
    pCOUNTRY = Value
End Property

Public Property Get CarTYPE() As String
    CarTYPE = pTYPE
End Property
Public Property Let CarTYPE(Value As String)
    pTYPE = Value
End Property

Public Function toString() As String
 toString = pID & "; " & _
            pMAKE & "; " & _
            pMODEL & "; " & _
            pDOORS & "; " & _
            pENGINE & "; " & _
            pCOUNTRY & "; " & _
            pTYPE
End Function
```

`clsCars`:

```
Private pCars As collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Set pCars = New collection
End Sub

Public Sub add(oCar As clsCar)
 pCars.add oCar
End Sub

Public Function getByIndex(lIndex As Long) As clsCar
 Set getByIndex = pCars.Item(lIndex)
End Function

Public Function getByID(lID As Long) As clsCar
 Dim oCar As clsCar
 For Each oCar In pCars
  If oCar.ID = lID Then
   Set getByID = oCar
  End If
 Next
End Function

Public Function getByEngine(sEngine As String) As collection
 Dim oCar As clsCar
 Set getByEngine = New collection
 For Each oCar In pCars
  If oCar.ENGINE = sEngine Then
   getByEngine.add oCar
  End If
 Next
End Function
```

`default Module`:

```
Public oCars As clsCars

Sub initialize()
 Dim oCar As clsCar
 Dim oListObject As ListObject
 Dim oListRow As ListRow
 Dim oCells As Range

 Set oCars = New clsCars

 Set oListObject = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblCarDesc")
 For Each oListRow In oListObject.ListRows
  Set oCells = oListRow.Range.Cells
  Set oCar = New clsCar
  oCar.ID = oCells(, 1).Value
  oCar.MAKE = oCells(, 2).Value
  oCar.MODEL = oCells(, 3).Value
  oCar.DOORS = oCells(, 4).Value
  oCar.ENGINE = oCells(, 5).Value
  oCars.add oCar
 Next

 Set oListObject = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblCarProd")
 Dim lID As Long
 For Each oListRow In oListObject.ListRows
  Set oCells = oListRow.Range.Cells
  lID = oCells(, 1).Value
  Set oCar = oCars.getByID(lID)
  If Not oCar Is Nothing Then
   oCar.COUNTRY = oCells(, 2).Value
   oCar.CarTYPE = oCells(, 3).Value
  End If
 Next

 MsgBox oCars.getByIndex(2).toString

 For Each oCar In oCars.getByEngine("V8")
  MsgBox oCar.toString
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Minor point, might be worth adding the car id as the collection key, you wouldn't need to loop through to get by ID then :)

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, but since the "ID" comes from a source which does not check uniqueness of the ID, I believe this would make things more difficult than bring advantages.

Comment: Ritcher Ok, horses for courses, I'd rather have an error so I know something is wrong than simply silently fail by only returning the first car. Nice solution anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

I would use a class for each, and an array of each also, so arrCars holds clsCars, and arrProd holds clsProduction.  I would then use the index of each for each array when populating, so arrCars(1)=Corvette and arrProd(1)=US Sport then from each you can refer to the others, so if x=3, cars(x) and prod(x) will be correct.  Or use a vlookup in excel first, and make one larger table, with the need for only 1 ID then, if that is the way they are related, but can a Bentley also be 3.  Its not quite clear what you mean by the 2nd table, is there an entry for each car, or is it like catgeorising the car further, just using a certain selection.  Another idea would be to have an extra property in the car class, of ProductionID and then use a static production "table" of classes to refer to.